# API (LoopBack) is not returning updated list after POST

Tags: reactjs, redux, loopbackjs

After saving an entity in the API (Loopback) I do a fetch to get the updated list of this entity but the returned list is not up to date. I mean, the new entity is not on the list.

I've done a lot of testing and there seems to be some king of 'cache' or 'transaction' between React and Loopback.
Even if I refresh the page, the list is still out of date. But if I wait a few minutes and refresh again the list come updated.

```
// Submit method 
    handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        var { name, description, id } = this.state
        await this.props.createStudentGroup({ name, description, id })

        this.props.fetchStudentGroupList(); // is the right place to do it ???

        this.props.showSuccess(`${name} successfully saved.`)
        this.resetForm();
    }

    // or should I use componentDidUpdate method ???
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        if (this.props.error === null && this.props.studentGroup.id !== null) {
            this.props.fetchStudentGroupList();
            this.props.resetStudentGroup();
        }
    }
```

I've tried both but did not work.

This problem only occurs on the development server on my machine functioned normally. :/

[1 - POST - it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlvU6.png)

[2- GET - doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsTjW.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can wait to get the response and after success you can get all students and on exception it will go to catch.

```
 handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var { name, description, id } = this.state
    this.props.createStudentGroup({ name, description, id }).then(response => {

        this.props.fetchStudentGroupList(); 

        this.props.showSuccess(`${name} successfully saved.`)
        this.resetForm();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    })
}
```

Comment: The line  ```await this.props.createStudentGroup({ name, description, id })``` does the same. 
Anyway I've tried as you said but didn't work.

Comment: @ViniciusSilva you can check if fetchStudentGroupList() is also async or not ? , if it is then you can wait to get all records.